# Does erasing a flash sector that is already erased cause wear?

Tags: nand-flash, nor-flash, erase

Does erasing a NOR flash sector cause any wear if it is already erased (and no data has been programmed into it)? I.e. does an erase count as a program/erase cycle? Some data sheets refer to max number of 'erase cycles' and others to 'program/erase cycles' and so on. Can I read anything into this, or are they the same thing w.r.t. wear?

What about NAND?